# Config merge conflict for field generatedID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

Hi I'm making a simple setState after getting a response of a socket API.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getDocument(socket).then((data) => {
      setVersion(data.version);
 
    });
  }, []);
```

The data.version is defined and works as expected but when I make the setVersion witch is a setState I got the error : Config merge conflict for field generatedID.

I'm making an extension for Codemirror inside Sandpack package to make it usable in collaborative mode